# The appropriate statistical model for categorical/binary DV + mixed design

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, repeated-measures

What R function should I use to build the appropriate logistic regression model if I have the following structure?

Independent variables

1. A categorical variable that varies between-subjects
2. A categorical variable that varies within-subjects
3. Another categorical variable that varies within-subjects

Dependent variable

1. Categorical variable with 2 possible outcomes: TRUE vs. FALSE

========================================

In addition to these, participants and test items will be treated as random effects.

I'm lost and I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are interested in fitting a *mixed effects (binary) logistic regression model*.  You'll likely need to recode your dependent variable so that it takes the value 0 (instead of FALSE) and 1 (instead of TRUE). Your model will include crossed random effects for participants and items.

The R function that you need to fit this type of model is the *glmer* function from the **lme4** package.

See this link for a detailed example of glmer's use in a setting similar to yours: http://people.linguistics.mcgill.ca/~morgan/book/mixed-effects-logistic-regression.html.